# Cloudfront Settings to Allow Requests only from certain MAC Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, web, acl, amazon-cloudfront

I have my HTTP Server serving my contents via Cloudfront and I wish to allow access to the contents only to certain MAC Addresses. Any clue how it could be done?

I have explored the possibility of Web ACL but that does not facilitate MAC option.

Have tried the IP Address option but as the address keeps changing for the white-list Origins, am relying on MAC here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you will be able to do this. The MAC address is not available to your browser, and if the browser doesn't have it, it can't provide it to cloudfront.

Comment: Then is there any other way to go about it?